# ~/Code Shared folder missing but never defined

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I try to setup a new Homestead VM with vagrant but if I try to start with `vagrant up`I get the information

```
vm:
* The host path of the shared folder is missing: ~/Code
```

But in my Homestead.yaml under `./src/stubs/` I set the folder property to:

```
folders:
    - map: J:/Eigene Daten/Gerrit/Development/PHP Storm/TestApp
      to: /home/vagrant/TestApp

sites:
    - map: vagrant.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/TestApp/public
```

Can anybody tell my why this happens?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It must be somewhere

You try to define a synchronized folder with `~/Code` but vagrant cannot find the folder. You can see by your self and create this `Code` directory in your home and `vagrant up` will work

We can't say where it is defined without looking at your configuration

Comment: I've searched in the whole homestead directory and only one result:

`J:\puphpet\Homestead\src\MakeCommand.php (1 hit)
 Line 103:             '- map: ~/Code', '- map: "'.str_replace('\\', '/',     $this->basePath).'"', $this->getHomesteadFile()`

Comment: ok but thats homestead source code, nothing in your Homestead.yaml ? and did you use this `make` command ? still try to create the `Code` folder to see if vagrant up will run correctly